# Using tcl split to solve `list element in braces followed by "]" instead of space` causes `unmatched open brace in list`

Tags: tcl

(This is from a nagelfar plugin -- it's a tcl analyzer written in tcl, which is why `$x` contains tcl code.)

In tcl shell:

```
% set x {proc {::$p} args {[subst { foo }]} }
proc {::$p} args {[subst { foo }]} 
% 
% lindex $x 3 0
list element in braces followed by "]" instead of space
```

According to http://forum.egghelp.org/viewtopic.php?t=2603 the solution is to use `split`, however:

```
% lindex [split $x] 3 0
unmatched open brace in list
```

What's the correct way to use `lindex` on a variable whose content is like the above `$x`?

Comment: The contents of procedures are scripts. Scripts are only a partially-overlapping syntactic space with lists; this isn't Lisp after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original string `$x` can be treated like a simple list...

```
% set x {proc {::$p} args {[subst { foo }]} }

% foreach item $x { puts $item}
proc
::$p
args
[subst { foo }]
```

...but not as a list of lists.   `[subst { foo }]` is not formatted properly to be a list.

```
% lindex $x 3 0
Error: list element in braces followed by "]" instead of space
        Use error_info for more info. (CMD-013)
```

A string can be treated like a [list in Tcl](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/list) if it can be separated by white space and optionally includes grouping with quotes or braces.  The last white space separated part of the string `[subst { foo }]` is `}]`.  This prevents first `{` character from forming a match for grouping.

For this specific string, you could first get the 4th item from `$x` and the use `split` to get the 1st item.

```
% lindex [split [lindex $x 3]] 0
[subst
```

In a general case, you could insert a space after every occurence of `}`.

```
% set y [regsub -all "\}" $x "\} "]
proc {::$p}  args {[subst { foo } ]}
% lindex $y 3 0
[subst
```